# show message on gridView update and dont save the changes

Tags: c#, .net

I have a gridview in my form. I want to check if the user inserts less than 7 numbers in column number.

If user insert less than 7 numbers do not accept and do not save the update value and show a message.

If insert more than 7 numbers, accept and save in gridview.

How to do this?

I try to make what I say but I failed.

This is my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns["emp_number"].Index == e.ColumnIndex)
    {
        if (e.FormattedValue.ToString().Trim() != "")
        {
            if (e.FormattedValue.ToString().Trim().Length < 7)
            {
                ms.error("less than 7");
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the error on the cell this way:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "less than 7";
//e.Cancel = true;
```

and at the final step check the existing error on the gridview with this method:

```
public bool HasErrorText(DataGridView dataGrid)
{
    bool hasErrorText = false;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.ErrorText.Length > 0)
            {
                hasErrorText = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (hasErrorText)
            break;
    }
    return hasErrorText;
}
```

You can even set the latest value to the cell if your validation fails something like this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns["emp_number"].Index == e.ColumnIndex)
    {
        if (e.FormattedValue.ToString().Trim() != "")
        {
            if (e.FormattedValue.ToString().Trim().Length < 7)
            {
                var latestValue = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
                dataGridView1.EditingControl.Text = Convert.ToString(latestValue);
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "less than 7";
                //e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```